# SOAP Fault: NullReferenceException

Tags: xml, soap, asp-classic, nullreferenceexception

**I am trying to connect to a webservice using Classic ASP. I am using the method FindCompanies... but its giving following error, confused on how to sort it please help**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
               at App.Apis.v_1_5.CompanyApi.FindCompanies(ApiCredentials credentials, String conditions, String orderBy, Nullable`1 limit, Nullable`1 skip)
               --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            </faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>   
</soap:Envelope>
```

**My ASP code is below**

```vb
<%
msURL = "https://myconnectwise.net/v4_6_release/apis/1.5/CompanyApi.asmx"

'set up xmlhttp to checkout server
Dim oRequest
Set oRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

'setting this option will allow ServerXMLHTTP to ignore the certificate errors it encounters.
oRequest.setOption(2) = SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS



' resolve, connect, send, receive - in milliseconds
oRequest.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000

msSOAP = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<s:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<FindCompanies xmlns=""http://connectwise.com/FindCompanies"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<CompanyName>training</CompanyName>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<IntegrationLoginId>xxx</IntegrationLoginId>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<IntegratorPassword>xxx</IntegratorPassword>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<Conditions>CompanyName like ""Connect*"" and City = ""new jersey""</Conditions>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "  <orderBy>string</orderBy>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "      <limit>int</limit>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "      <skip>int</skip>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</FindCompanies>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</s:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</s:Envelope>"

oRequest.Open "POST", msURL, False
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://connectwise.com/FindCompanies"
oRequest.send msSOAP

Response.Write oRequest.responseText
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your given [asmx link](https://myconnectwise.net/v4_6_release/apis/1.5/CompanyApi.asmx) the [wsdl](https://myconnectwise.net/v4_6_release/apis/1.5/CompanyApi.asmx?WSDL) prints out a demo request (just open in browser!)

So I think your request misses **some parameters/has some wrong tags/structure**! Sending in this generated demo request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="http://connectwise.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <con:FindCompanies>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <con:credentials>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <con:CompanyId>asdf</con:CompanyId>
        <con:ContactId>123</con:ContactId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <con:IntegratorLoginId>asdf</con:IntegratorLoginId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <con:IntegratorPassword>asdf</con:IntegratorPassword>
        <con:PortalConfigId>123</con:PortalConfigId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <con:MachineId>asdf</con:MachineId>
      </con:credentials>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <con:conditions>asdf</con:conditions>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <con:orderBy>asdf</con:orderBy>
      <con:limit>123</con:limit>
      <con:skip>123</con:skip>
    </con:FindCompanies>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

did give me a result!

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Cannot find company in connectwise config.xml: asdf</faultstring>
         <faultactor>PSA</faultactor>
         <detail>
            <text>Cannot find company in connectwise config.xml: asdf</text>
            <type>CompanyNotFoundError</type>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this issue as well. It seems the value provided in `<CompanyName>training</CompanyName>` is not the same company name/id you use when logging into Connectwise. If it is the same make sure it is the one you logged in with when you created the Integrator Login as I believe they get tied together at that point.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess I'd say part of the problem is the *OrderBy*, *limit* and *skip* fields don't appear to have correct values. i.e.

*OrderBy* should be the name of a column
*limit* should be a number
*skip* should be a number

(This is of course just a guess, I don't know how the API works!)

The error is basically saying that the service can't find a variable or it hasn't been initialised correctly (Object reference not set to instance of an object).

Answer (score 0):

Read the fault message. It is clearly an exception *in the service*. The service has thrown a `NullReferenceException`.

If this is due to the parameters you are passing, then it is *still* a bug in the service - the parameters should have been checked before the service operation began.